# Django template custom filter does not change size of button

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django template variable and custom filter inside a button stylized with bootstrap 4.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-left mb-2" disabled>
    {{ my_variable | my_filter}}
</button>
```

If `my_filter`increases the length of `my_variable`, I find that the size of the button is not automatically extended as I assume that its size is processed by Django before the filter is applied. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The size of the button is not determined by Django. The filters are applied at the *server* side, so the HTML that it generates looks like `<button ...>somevalue</button>`. Django thus has no control over the button size/style/... since that is done by the browser.

Comment: thus likely the button style simply will not change in general.